# How to remove the line between Dialog title and Dialog Body?

Tags: java-me, dialog, lwuit

When calling `Dialog.show("title", "text", "ok", "cancel")` then in runtime there is a line break between the Dialog title and its body. How to remove this line break because the Dialog is not very pretty to look ?

Comment: This is not a line. This is the border of dialog title.

Comment: @bhakki: So how to remove the dialog title border ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DialogTitle` border to empty on ResourceEdit. Also you can set the `DialogContentPane` border to empty on ResourceEdit.